# Is it possible to colorize brackets in the notebook editor to see matches more easily?

Tags: notebooks, editing

I've seen that if I click on a square bracket `[`, I can then use "Check Balance" in the right click menu to see where the matching bracket is.

Is there a way to see different levels of brackets in different colors?  The closest that I've found is 'Show larger' for bracket matching syntax errors under preferences.

If there's no way to colorize bracket nesting, is there a keyboard shortcut for "Check Balance" like <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> in Vim for C code?

Comment: If you make it a habit to press a return before each closing bracket you will see it lines up with the Function it belongs to. This is true only if the syntax is correct, otherwise you see incorrect indentations, which, on their own, are also a useful cue to have.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to hit Return before each closing bracket; you can go back and put the Return characters in later, when you want to see the brackets lined up. As we all know, Mathematica treats Return differently from Enter -- an unfortunate inheritance from Apple's old development environment, MPW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If there's no way to colorize bracket nesting, is there a keyboard
>   shortcut for "Check Balance" like shift-% in VIM for C-code?

Yes, right from [the help file](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html):

> Check Balance     <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: Since the gist of the question is about colorization, I'd say shift-ctrl-B could have been a comment, don't you think?

Comment: As I now quote in my answer the question specifically asks for the keyboard shortcut as a fallback.