# Suggest allowing new color brackets

Tags: notebooks

By now I have spent a bit of effort in writing Mathematica notebook for my analysis tasks and appreciate the power of the Mathematica language. At the same time, I also discover that a significant fraction of my time had been spent on balancing the (, [ and { bracket, or scratching my head to discover that the weird results I got were due to improper placement of the closing brackets. I wonder if the code developers have considered allowing different colors to make my chore easier. An example may be that every time an open bracket is invoked, whether (, [ or {, a new and different color is attached to that bracket, and likewise, at closing. In this manner, if an improper placement is made, I would discover it immediately. Just a suggestion.

Comment: What is wrong with this? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3802/1089 (as advertised on the right of your question in Related on this site?)